# Proving $xy+uv\leq\sqrt{x^2+u^2}\sqrt{y^2+v^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How do I prove the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality?

> $$xy+uv\leq \sqrt{x^2+u^2} \sqrt{y^2+v^2}$$
>   with $x,y,u,v \in \mathbb{R} $

Comment: That **is** Cauchy-Schwarz. So your question is "Can I prove Cauchy-Schwarz without using Cauchy-Schwarz?" I suggest you use your favourite way of proving Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$xy+uv <0$$ it is true.

if $$xy+uv\ge 0$$ we take the square and prove that

$$2xyuv\le x^2v^2+y^2u^2$$  which is true since
$$x^2v^2+y^2u^2-2xyuv=(xv-yu)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Of course:
$$ (x^2+u^2)(y^2+v^2) = (xy+uv)^2\color{red}{+(xv-uy)^2} $$
is Lagrange's identity, straightforward to check.

Answer (score 1):

if $$xy+uv<0$$ then our inequality is true.
In the other case we get by squaring
$$x^2y^2+u^2v^2+2xyuv\le x^2y^2+y^2u^2+x^2v^2+u^2v^2$$
so we get
$$(yu-xv)^2\geq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the inequality is homogeneous for the two set of the letters  we may assume that $x^2+u^2=1$ and $y^2+v^2=1.$ Then we have to prove inequality
$$
xy+uv \leq 1.
$$
We have $2xy \leq x^2+y^2$ and $2uv\leq u^2+v^2.$ Thus 
$$
2xy+2uv \leq x^2+y^2+u^2+v^2=2 \implies xy+uv \leq 1.
$$